# propaganda coup -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Vladimir Putin’s worst nightmare may be happening right now](http://www.cnbc.com/id/102235487#) (CNBC)

> "I think we are likely to see much more decline than anybody now predicts," he says.
>
> Other observers say that while Putin can still count on the **propaganda coup** his state media machine has pulled off, it's only because Russians haven't had to cope with the downturn for long.

What is "**propaganda coup**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coup is a major achievement, often against odds.  A propaganda coup is such an achievement in shaping public opinion.